# Flutter web contact form EmailJs ( sending emails empty )

Tags: email, flutter-web, contact-form

I was trying to create a portfolio in flutter web,
then i wanted to add a contact form. I used EmailJS.
When I hit the "send" button I get emails but they are blank...

How can i fix this? can you help me?

[image: Here is my EmailJS template]

[image: I get this mail when i press the button]

[image: sendEmail]

and this is part of my code

```
Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: messageController,
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            minLines: 10,
                            maxLines: 15,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'Enter Your Message',
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Color(0xFF66FcF1),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: OutlinedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  sendEmail(
                                      email: '',
                                      message: '',
                                      name: '',
                                      subject: '');
                                },
                                child: const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Submit',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xFF66FcF1),
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works correctly since your message is sent, except on line `message: ' ',` you didn't add the message content that should be sent.

The solution is this,

```
onPressed: () {
               sendEmail(
               email: '',
               message: _messageController.text.trim(),
               name: '',
               subject: '');
     },
```

I would also suggest you provide fields to fill all the other fields for a better end user experience.

Answer (score 1):

you're sending empty strings

```
sendEmail(
 email: '',
 message: '',
 name: '',
 subject: '');
},
```

try instead with TextFormField(). Don't forget you have to define the controller for the input to get your strings. And then it should work.

```
 Form(
   key: _formKey,    
     TextFormField(
      controller: controllerMensagem,
      validator: (value) {
       if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
         return '*required';
       }
      return null;
      },
     ),
   ),
```